# Просмотр сгенерированой XML (KSOAP2)

Tags: java, android, soap

Пытаюсь просмотреть сгенерированную xml:

```
httpTransport.debug = true;
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
AppLog.e(httpTransport.requestDump);
AppLog.e(httpTransport.responseDump);
```

Выдает пустую строку в лог, в чем может быть проблема? Почему не выводится xml?

Comment: А на сервер запрос доходит, сервер отдает xml ?

Comment: @KirillStoianov нет, получаю на устройстве HTTP request failed, HTTP status 500, хотя  сам сервер работает, проверяла через SoapUI, сервер отдает  xml.

Comment: @KirillStoianov пытаюсь выяснить в чем ошибка, для этого хочу вывести в Log хотя бы сгенерированную xml реквеста.

Comment: 500 ошибка - ошибка сервера. думаю стоит проверить параметры с которыми ты делаешь запрос на сервер. Похоже сервер не может обработать запрос, он ничего не отдает, поэтому и в логах пусто.

Comment: URL тоже проверь

Comment: @KirillStoianov Параметры и URL совпадают с теми, что я тестирую через SoapUI

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43138/discussion-between-kirill-stoianov-and-lucky-girl).

Comment: на сервер нужно отправить POST или GET запрос, с андроида ты отправляешь POST или GET
заголовки которые ты отправляешь правельные? Content-Type и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увидеть в Логах сгенерированную `xml` так и не удалось, зато, когда перешла в режим `Debugger`, то там смогла просмотреть `xml`, как для `request` так и  для `response`.